# Google API response time very high

Tags: c#, azure, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using google RESTApis  to manage google calendar

One particular api call to check current "access token is valid or not" is taking extra time(2 minutes) only in azure environment and the same call is only taking few seconds in localhost and other non azure environments.

```
string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo?access_token=" + AccessToken;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "POST";

byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Empty);

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
}

var resp = request.GetResponse();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a little surprised Google lets you use TLS 1.1 at all. If your framework version is 4.5+ , remove the line that sets SecurityProtocol and see if there is any difference.

Comment: Interesting, how about other hosts? Does `google.com` take that long to resolve as well?

Comment: `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers` says Google accepts TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2, that shouldn't be the problem, and doesn't explain the timeout, TLS handshakes fail under a second.